# Taking unrelated code out of views.py

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am using [`django-filter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) app, which this question relates to but after all it's pretty much python/django generic.

A little rundown, of how the app normally works: filters accept `lookup_type` parameter. They behave like django forms, eg.

`filters.py`

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    price = django_filters.NumberFilter(lookup_type='lt')
```

Then `views.py`

```
from .filters import ProductFilter

def product_list(request):
    filtered_data = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'f': filtered_data})
```

This works fine but what if I wanted a site visitor be able to specify `lookup_type` explicitly and filter based on his choice? One solution I came up with, was to take all the code from `filters.py` to `views.py`:

```
def product_list(request):
    lookup_type_user = request.GET.get('lookup_type', 'exact')

    class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
         price = django_filters.NumberFilter(lookup_type=lookup_type_user)

    filtered_data = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    # ...
```

This works but I'd like to keep the code in separate files. Do you have any ideas maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function in your filter module that creates your filter class.

```
def filter_factory(lookup_type):
    class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
         price = django_filters.NumberFilter(lookup_type=lookup_type)

    return ProductFilter
```

Then import the `filter_factory` in your views.

```
from .filters import filter_factory

def product_list(request):
    lookup_type_user = request.GET.get('lookup_type', 'exact')
    ProductFilter = filter_factory(lookup_type_user)
    filtered_data = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'f': filtered_data})
```

Comment: Appreciated. Finally I got the context where nesting a class inside a function was useful. Now, I'll remember.